# Why does TimeSpan.Milliseconds evaluate to 0?

Tags: .net, timespan, milliseconds

Why does `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).Milliseconds` evaluate to `0` when it would seem more correct for it to evaluate to `30000`?

Comment: Did you check the documentation before asking? It looks pretty clear to me. In particular, if you'd seen: "The return value ranges from -999 through 999" that should have caused you to doubt your claim that it should return 30000 in your situation...

Comment: Tooltip in the IDE: `Gets the number of whole milliseconds represented by the current TimeSpan structure.`

Comment: So you went straight from tooltip to Stack Overflow, without taking the 10 seconds it would have taken to type "msdn TimeSpan.Milliseconds" into your browser search engine?

Comment: I did have some trust in the quality of the tooltips provided in the IDE - never again! In any case, isn't it a SO principle that Google-able questions can be asked here?

Comment: It's a principle that questions should have a degree of research done on them before asking. I don't count trusting in a single sentence from a tooltip as adequate research.

Comment: The tooltip is actually the same as what's on MSDN online so that wouldn't have been any help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.milliseconds(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It would have done if you'd read more than the first line of the documentation. Whenever you think something's a little bit odd, *surely* it makes sense to read the whole documentation page, rather than just the first line.

Comment: This one caught me, too.  The property names aren't clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

`TotalMilliseconds` is what you are looking for.  `Milliseconds` returns the "remainder" milliseconds (i.e. the partial second)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `TotalMilliseconds` instead of `Milliseconds`. `Milliseconds` return only the part of milliseconds of the DateTime "01:01:01:342" will return 342 milliseconds.